# Trying to transform items in data frame. Maybe JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am importing data from a database and I only need one field.  I can get the one field just fine, but the data in that one field looks really messy, like this.

```
[
    {'id': 360014571631, 'default': False, 'name': '200 - OK', 'raw_name': '200 - OK', 'value': 'purpose_add/remove_user'},
    {'id': 360014571651, 'default': False, 'name': 'Change Permissions', 'raw_name': 'Change Permissions', 'value': 'purpose_change_permissions'}, 
    {'id': 360014571671, 'default': False, 'name': 'Failed Data Validation', 'raw_name': 'Failed Data Validation', 'value': 'purpose_failed_data_validation'},
    {'id': 360014571691, 'default': False, 'name': 'Grant Access', 'raw_name': 'Grant Access', 'value': 'purpose_grant_access'},
]
```

I would like to clean it up and get it into another data frame. So, I want to drop the single apostrophe, as well as the square brackets and curly brackets (pretty easy).  Finally I want to split everything based on commas and assign the name to the left of the colon as the new field name.  So, I want to get it into this format.

That's what I can't figure out.  I'm not sure if it's a pivot or a transpose or a melt.  I don't know what to call this.  It's definitely some kind of transformation on the data set.

```
id  default name    raw_name    value   etc., etc., etc.
360014571631        FALSE   200 - OK    200 - OK    purpose_add/remove_user   etc., etc., etc.
```

When I export the data to a CSV, I see this:

[image]

Note: some records look like this:

```
                                       []
```

I tried this:

```
df1[df1.custom_field_options.str.contains("[]") == False]
```

I received this error:

```
error: unterminated character set
```

If I run Ben's data set, it actually works like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe missing something about the transformation you are after, but as described I think you just want to create the dataframe from your list of dictionaries.

using your data:

```
data = [{'id': 360014571631, 'default': False, 'name': '200 - OK', 'raw_name': '200 - OK', 'value': 'purpose_add/remove_user'}, {'id': 360014571651, 'default': False, 'name': 'Change Permissions', 'raw_name': 'Change Permissions', 'value': 'purpose_change_permissions'}, {'id': 360014571671, 'default': False, 'name': 'Failed Data Validation', 'raw_name': 'Failed Data Validation', 'value': 'purpose_failed_data_validation'}, {'id': 360014571691, 'default': False, 'name': 'Grant Access', 'raw_name': 'Grant Access', 'value': 'purpose_grant_access'}]
```

you can transform that into a dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data)
```

which returns:

```
       default            id                    name                raw_name  value
0    False  360014571631                200 - OK                200 - OK   purpose_add/remove_user
1    False  360014571651      Change Permissions      Change Permissions   purpose_change_permissions
2    False  360014571671  Failed Data Validation  Failed Data Validation   purpose_failed_data_validation
3    False  360014571691            Grant Access            Grant Access   purpose_grant_access
```

if you wanted to get it into JSON.

```
df.to_json()
```

which you can find here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: I don't see how that helps.  After I run that process, I get almost the same thing:  
,custom_field_options
19,"[{'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Public', 'raw_name': 'Public', 'value': 'public'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Private', 'raw_name': 'Private', 'value': 'private'}]"
20,"[{'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Private', 'raw_name': 'Private', 'value': 'private_dataset'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Pubic', 'raw_name': 'Pubic', 'value': 'pubic_dataset'}]"